# use my Add-on for google docs on all my docs (and publish it)

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created an appscript for google docs, its purpose is to edit the document currently in use. It is really simple, there is only a few functions including the "onOpen" one. For now it's only working on a particular document. How can I make it working on all my google docs?(and how would I been able to post it?). I know that it's a really simple question but I'm a beginner and I'm not finding any solutions on the web.
Have a nice day.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jcc3xm7aRU&t=5s&ab_channel=uneasyguy

Comment: Assuming that you don't  interact with the script nor can you utilize DocumentApp.getUi() in any way.  You can openById() and run your script.   If you interact with the script then it  will have to be installed in your container so you would have to create an addon.